# DATE FORMATTING - COGNOS

Tags: date, cognos-10

I am using cognos version 10 and I need my dates to display in this format 'yyyy-mm' but it is showing dates like '2014-04' as '2014-4' so it is reading the dates out of order by producing '2014-11' first because it starts with a one. I need to add a zero to those double digit integers that way the months(specifically) will display in order.

here's an the code I've created in attempt:

```
_year( start_date ) ||'-'|| _month( start_date )

IF(_month(start_date) > 10)
THEN('0' +_month(start_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  Use `yyyy-MM`.

Your question lacks a lot of detail, so my response is based on considerable guess-work.

Are you asking about formatting, or do you want to transform the values?  Formatting can be done without code.  The code for your data item should be `start_date`.

Is this for a *List column body*?  Where do you enter your format (`yyyy-mm`)?  Are you using the *Data format* property?

In the **Data format** dialog, if you can't find another setting that will do what you want, you can enter a pattern into the *Pattern* property.  If you look at the tips at the bottom of the **Data format** dialog, you'll notice that using `yyyy-mm` would give you a four digit year, a hyphen, and a two-digit minute.  Perhaps you should try `yyyy-MM`.  It works for me.

As for sorting:  Even if you used `yyyy-M` for the pattern, 2014-04-22 (displayed as 2014-4), should sort before 2014-11-01 (displayed as 2014-11).  The only reason the sort would be wrong is if it is using some other data besides the dates.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree that I may not have given enough detail, but I did find that making it into a cast function:

    cast(_month(field), varchar(2))

made a big deal. Furthermore, to join the string zero to that function with || was useful if the month was less than 10.

Thanks again. Hopeful if anyone with cognos runs into this issue, they can sooner resolve.

Comment: had to concatenate a zero at the beginning of the months less than 10 using || for cognos